# Пытаюсь вытянуть информацию о видео с MySQL через апи в реакт

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, laravel, api

У меня есть функция в ларе которой можно загрузить видео в бд, но когда хочу вывести в реакт
то не получается воспроизвести видео, не могу понять почему, ошибок в консоли не выдаёт
код с лары :

```
 public function store(Request $request){
   $data =  $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        'video' => 'required|file|mimes:mp4,mov,avi|max:100000'
    ]);

    if ($request->hasFile('image')){
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $imageName = time() . '_' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $data['image'] = $imageName;

        $request->image->move(public_path('storage/images'), $imageName);
    }

    if ($request->hasFile('video')) {
        $video = $request->file('video');
        $videoName = time() . '_' . $video->getClientOriginalName();
        $data['video'] = $videoName;

        $request->video->move(public_path('storage/videos'), $videoName);
    }

    Post::create($data);

    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('Post.listPost', ['posts'=>$posts]);
}
```

код с реакта :

```
function PostDetail() {
const { id } = useParams();
const [post, setPost] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post?id=${id}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setPost(data))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
}, [id]);

return (
    <div className="post_detail">
        <div className="post_details_watch">
            <video className="post_detail_video" controls>
                <source src={post.video} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
            <img src={post.image} alt=""/>

            <p>{post.name}</p>
            <p>Plot Summary :</p>
            <p>Содержание: {post.description}</p>
        </div>

    </div>
);
```

}

Comment: Пытался и так делать  
<video className="post_detail_video" controls>
                    <source src={`http://localhost:3000/storage/videos/${post.video}`} type="video/mp4" />
</video>

Comment: *И где здесь* видео в "MySQL" я стесняюсь спросить?

Comment: И при этом код контроллера, "вытягивающего"  информацию, разумеется, отсутствует

Comment: @Ипатьев  
<video className="post_detail_video" controls>
                <source src={post.video} type="video/mp4" />
            </video>

Comment: @Ипатьев через fetch обращаюсь и спокойно себе вытягиваю, не подтягивается только видео, даже если ссылку с ютуба вставляешь - пишет что ютуб не разрешает вопроизводить видео

Comment: @Ипатьев Может я конечно не сильно понимаю, но подскажите где и что добавить ибо вариантов у меня уже нету

Comment: вы хоть консоль логом покажите, что с бэкэнда приходит...и код геттера с ларавел(тот что на /api/post?id=${id} отвечает)